# About formula deducibility from theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

In the book "Model theory" of Mr.Chang and Mr.Keisler we have such definition:
[image]

Issue is: what if we consider negation of $\varphi(v_0, \dots,v_n)$? Say we consider, that $\varphi$ isn't deducible from $Σ$ (i.e. it isn't consistent with $\Sigma$), then $\lnot \varphi$ does. But from that definition for $\varphi$, as for any other regular formula, we have $Σ ⊨ (∀ v_0 \dots v_n) ¬\varphi(v_0,\dots,v_n)$.

Am I right?

Comment: Oh. you right, I forgot to add "¬" in front of phi, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\varphi$ is not a consequence of $\Sigma$ implies (but it is not equivalent to say) that $\varphi$ is not consistent with $\Sigma$ (that is, no model of $\Sigma$ satifies $\varphi$), but it does not imply that $\lnot \varphi$ is a consequence of $\Sigma$.

For instance, let $\Sigma$ be the set of axioms for being a group (a model satisfies $\Sigma$ iff it is a group), and let $\varphi$ be the formula that expresses that the group is abelian. Now, $\varphi$ is not a consequence of $\Sigma$ because not every group is abelian, but it is not true that $\lnot\varphi$ is a consequence of $\Sigma$ because there are abelian groups.

---

More formally, the notion of (*logical*) *consequence*$-$aka *deducibility*$-$is a bit delicate. Moreover, pay attention to not confuse the operation of negating a formula with the operation of negating that a formula is a consequence of a set of sentences.

1. First, let us see what negating a formula means with respect to the notion of consequence. That is, let us apply the definition of consequence you posted to a formula $\varphi(v_0, \dots, v_n) = \lnot \psi(v_0, \dots, v_n)$. A formula $\lnot \psi(v_0, \dots, v_n)$ is a consequence of $\Sigma$, noted $\Sigma \models \lnot \psi(v_0, \dots, v_n)$, iff for *every* model $\mathfrak{A}$ and *every* sequence $a_0, \dots, a_n \in A$, $a_0, \dots, a_n$ satisfies $\lnot \psi$, which is equivalent to say that for *every* model $\mathfrak{A}$ and *every* sequence $a_0, \dots, a_n \in A$, $a_0, \dots, a_n$ doeas not satisfy $\psi$.
2. Negating that a formula is a consequence of a set of sentences amounts to negate the English sentence in the definition you posted: a formula $\varphi(v_0, \dots, v_n)$ is *not* a consequence of a set of sentences $\Sigma$, noted $\Sigma \not\models \varphi(v_0, \dots, v_n)$, iff *there is* a model $\mathfrak{A}$ and a sequence $a_0, \dots, a_n \in A$ such that $a_0, \dots, a_n$ does not satisfy $\varphi$.

Do you see the difference in quantifiers used for 1. and for 2.? This means that $\Sigma \not\models \varphi(v_0, \dots, v_n)$ does not imply $\Sigma \models \lnot\varphi(v_0, \dots, v_n)$. In other words, if
a formula is not a consequence of a set of sentences, the negation of that formula need not be a consequence of that set of sentences. This is exactly what you are ignoring when you say:

> $φ$ isn't deducible from $Σ$ (i.e. it isn't consistent with $\Sigma$), then $¬φ$ does.

---

There is a special case where the fact that $\varphi$ is not a consequence of $\Sigma$ implies (and actually is equivalent to say) that $\lnot \varphi$ is a consequence of $\Sigma$: this holds when the set of sentences $\Sigma$ is *complete*, that is, for every formula $\varphi$, either $\Sigma \models \varphi$ or $\Sigma \models \lnot\varphi$.

However, many important sets of sentences are not complete. For instance, first-order Peano arithmetic, the theory of groups, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I should to use other designation, for the set of formulas yes, it's so, but what about theories, and especially, complete theories? Will it work in that case? If I should make new question for that just say, I will mark your answer as best and make new question.

Comment: @Timur - What do you mean by "theory"? I added a remark about a complete set of formulas.

Comment: Chang and Keisler use it in their book, it says "first-order theory is a set of sentences". But never mind, I just would like to make it clear, is my initial statement about bounding of ¬φ outside in the case of complete theory true? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Timur - Ok, it does not change anything in my answer. To be coherent with the definitions you are using, I will edit my answer by replacing ¨set of formulas" with "set of sentences¨.

Comment: thank you for such fast response, please, could you answer on my last mini- clarification in the end of my comment? :)

Comment: @Timur - I'm not sure to understand the question in your comment. Can you make it more explicit? Maybe it would be better to open another post for that question.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote to my answer? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I see dark triangle over upvote, so I upvoted it,  check it now

Comment: @Timur - Don't worry. I received 3 upvotes and 1 downvote. I would like to understand the reason for the downvote, if the voter (I don't know who is) comes back.